# php regex remove digits

Tags: php, regex

I need a regex to remove the digits from a string but not also the spaces. I currently have

```
$city_location = 'UK,0113|Leeds new york';
$sip_city = '0113Leeds new york';
 $city = preg_replace('/[^a-z]/i', '', $sip_city);
```

It removes the digits but also the spaces so I need a regex which won't remove the spaces.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `\d` if you want to remove all digits

```
$city = preg_replace('/\d/', '', $sip_city);
```

Or `[^a-z\s]` if you want to replace all except alphabets and whitespaces

```
$city = preg_replace('/[^a-z\s]/i', '', $sip_city);
```

Comment: I think you don't need the `i` flag here :)

Comment: Michael just wants to remove the digits but your code would remove special charactes like $,@,# or others. what it wont remove is letters of the alphabet and spaces.what do u say about my quote below

Comment: @lovesh, my first solution will _only_ remove digits.

Answer (score 3):

use

```
$city = preg_replace('/[0-9]/', '', $sip_city);
```

in your code the `regex engine` doesnt match anything that is not in the alphabet that is `A-Z` and `a-z`. so spaces are not in the alphabet and they get matched.
i dont have much experience with regex but one thing which i have understood is that

> it is better to tell the regex engine
>   what u want rather than telling what u
>   dont want