# PHP regex remove all digits except character codes

Tags: php, regex

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397582/php-regex-remove-digits) thread it's pretty easy to remove all digits from a string in PHP.

For example:

```
$no_digits = preg_replace('/\d/', '', 'This string contains digits! 1234');
```

But, I don't want digits removed that are part of HTML charactr codes such as:

```
&#41;
&#169;
```

How can I get Regex to ignore numbers that are part of a HTML character code? i.e. numbers that are sandwiched between `&#` and `;` characters?

Comment: You'd probably need to include the hex version as well.

Comment: And you could probably just use the whole entity construct without being specific. `'~(?i:[&%](?:[a-z]+|(?:\#(?:[0-9]+|x[0-9a-f]+)));(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\d+)~'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `(*SKIP)(*F)` verb:

```
echo preg_replace('/&#\d+;(*SKIP)(*F)|\d+/', '', 
                  'This string contains digits! 1234 &#41; &#169; 5678');
//=> This string contains digits!  &#41; &#169;
```

`&#\d+;(*SKIP)(*F)` will skip the match id regex matches `&#\d+;` pattern.

Alternatively you can use lookarounds:

```
echo preg_replace('/(?<!&#)\d+|\d+(?!;)/', '',
                  'This string contains digits! 1234 &#41; &#169; 5678');
```

Which means match 1 or digits that are either not preceded by `&#` OR not followed by `;` thus making it skip `&#\d+;` pattern.

Comment: Does php see `*F` as *FAIL ?

Comment: Yes `*F` is just a shortcut for `*FAIL`

Comment: @sln Indeed, `(*F)` = `(?!)` = `(*FAIL)`.

Comment: How about does `(*S)` = `(*SKIP)` ?

Comment: No that is not valid in PCRE

Comment: I'd stick with the `(*skip)(*fail)` regex, this one `(?<!&#)\d+|\d+(?!;)` will not match how you think it will.  I.e. since you can't split up the conditions in an alternation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
var output = Regex.Replace(input, @"[\d-]", string.Empty);
```

***The `\d` identifier simply matches any digit character.

Comment: That is javascript, OP is in PHP. Also `\d` only matches `0-9`, single digit, need a quantifier for tens/hunderds/thousands/etc.

Answer (score 0):

As an option, you could convert your code to UTF-8 encoding (if it’s not already UTF-8), then convert HTML entities to corresponding *characters* with `html_entity_decode()`, then remove numbers with a regexp, then, if needed, convert special characters to corresponding entities again with `htmlentities()` (in UTF-8, it’s actually enough to escape just a minimal subset of special characters via `htmlspecialchars()`), then convert code back to your original encoding (if the original string was not in UTF-8).

Answer (score -1):

You can use look behind and look ahead.

```
$no_digits = preg_replace('/(?<!&#)\d+(?=[^;\d])/', '', 'This string contains &#41; digits! 1234');
```

So basically, `(?<!&#)` tells RegEx to look behind `\d+` to make sure that there is no `&#` and `(?=[^;\d])` tells RegEx to look ahead of `\d+` to make sure that it is not a semicolon or a number.

I like this solution a bit better as it can be used on most RegEx like in Java and JavaScript.

Hope this helps.

Edit: miss one character `<`.

Comment: This `(?!&#)\d+` segment _looks ahead_ for not `&#` then matches `\d` which can never be `&#`

Comment: It is a 'look behind'. The RegEx engine first looks for `\d`. Once found, it looks behind to see if it is not `&#` then it will trigger `\d` found. It is a relative thing. :-p

Comment: No it's a lookahead.

Comment: Hahaha, I see what you guys means. I miss a `&lt;`. Cheers.

Comment: Ok, so `(?<!&#)\d+(?=[^;\d])` runs into the same problem as with @anubhava 's _alternation_ regex. You've _split_ the condition which won't work separately. If either one is satisfied seperate but not together, it will miss a valid `\d` ...example: It won't match `555`; nor &#`77`x

Comment: @sln Oh, that is right. Totally forgot about that. Thanks.